# Cartesian product between n attributes and their values in mysql (Cartesian product)

Tags: mysql

EDIT:
What I mean by dynamic is that if I add another attribute such as storage I don't want to change the query much. Storage could have 32gb or 64gb which then creates a total 18 combinations. Right now I would have to add another join and more columns to select. I would like to be able to just change a list of attribute ids and it would create a comma separated list of attribute names and ids.

I have 2 attributes color and size. Each attribute has one or more values.

**Example:**

```
Color: red, yellow, blue

Size: small, medium, large
```

I need to create a query that will create a list of all possible combinations given any number of attributes.

In this case it would be:

```
Red    small    
red    medium    
red    large    
yellow small    
yellow medium    
yellow large
```

I have come up with a way to do it for 2 attributes but I need it to be more dynamic

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `phppos_attribute_values` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ecommerce_attribute_term_id` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `attribute_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `deleted` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `name_attribute_id` (`name`,`attribute_id`),
  KEY `phppos_attribute_values_ibfk_1` (`attribute_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `phppos_attribute_values_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`attribute_id`) REFERENCES `phppos_attributes` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

Query:

```
SELECT a1.name,a1.id,a2.name,a2.id 
FROM phppos_attribute_values a1 
JOIN phppos_attribute_values as a2 ON a2.attribute_id = 2 
WHERE a1.attribute_id = 1
```

Result:

```
+--------+----+--------+----+
| name   | id | name   | id |
+--------+----+--------+----+
| red    |  1 | small  |  7 |
| red    |  1 | medium |  8 |
| red    |  1 | large  |  9 |
| yellow |  2 | small  |  7 |
| yellow |  2 | medium |  8 |
| yellow |  2 | large  |  9 |
| blue   |  3 | small  |  7 |
| blue   |  3 | medium |  8 |
| blue   |  3 | large  |  9 |
+--------+----+--------+----+
```

In the end I need just the ids of all combinations.

The query above works but it is static; I want to be able to have it take attribute ids dynamically instead of having to change the query each time I add an attribute.

Comment: What do you mean "dynamic" here. Share some sample data of more than one "attribute_id" and what your desired results would be. It's not clear from the text alone.

Comment: I put what I mean by dynamic in the question.

Comment: I see. So if you add "Storage" as an attribute then instead of just `"color, size"` as an output with 9 combos you would want `"color, size, storage"` as an output with 18 combos (assuming 2 storages were added). This is a doozie of a problem. With a different RDBMS I could see doing a really ugly recursive CTE. Perhaps a procedure to stitch the sql together and then execute it.. dynamically.

Comment: Ok so your suggestion would be to stitch together sql? It would be really nice if I could do this at the database level; but I can make a string builder too

Comment: There may be a way using variables in mysql's syntax, but I'm not familiar enough to say. I'm guessing by the lack of community input here, that this isn't going to be an easy one to solve short of writing the sql out dynamically and executing it. Never a great option, but sometimes it's the only way to crack the nut.